# Coupled many body quantum harmonic oscillator in 3 Dimension

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator, many-body, coupled-oscillators

Can coupled many body quantum harmonic oscillator be solved exactly ? $$H=\sum_{i}\dfrac{\vec{p}_{i}^{2}}{2m}+\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{k,j}K(\vec{R_{k}}-\vec{R}_{j})^{2}$$. Is there any reference to solve this exactly.

Comment: The 1d version is well-known.  Here, how do you order your particles?  i.e. how do you define $k+1$ being “neighbor” to $k$ in 3d?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you've set the spring constant to unity? That's an unusual choice of convention which will make your results much harder to compare to others in the literature. If you must set stuff to unity, set $k=m\omega^2$ to start with, and then in that order set $m=1$ and $\hbar=1$. Setting $\omega=1$ for your problem's energy scale is just asking for trouble, but setting $E=\hbar\omega=\hbar/\sqrt{m}$ for your energy scale is even worse.

Comment: It was a mistake ...the spring constant is not unity.

Answer (score 4):

It's a special case of

$$ H = \sum_i \frac{P_i^2}{2m} + \sum_{ij} Q_{ij} X_i X_j $$

where $Q_{ij}$ is a real symmetric matrix. Since $Q_{ij}$ is orthogonally diagonisable, the system is equivalent to a set of uncoupled harmonic oscillators. In principle, everything you could want to compute can then be expressed in terms of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $Q_{ij}$.

Better still, the three dimensions of your system are actually uncoupled, so the system is equivalent to three copies of the equivalent 1D system. The above method can be applied to each system, and IIRC the diagonalisation of $Q_{ij}$ can be carried out exactly and the eigenvectors are given in terms of Chebyshev polynomials.

Comment: Thank you so much. However, can anyone suggest a good reference wherein I can look for the solutions of the the matrix that you defined