# Continuation of my previous questions on coupled harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator, normal-modes

[Coupled many body quantum harmonic oscillator in 3 Dimension](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/400736/coupled-many-body-quantum-harmonic-oscillator-in-3-dimension?noredirect=1#comment898589_400736)

$$H=\sum_{j}\frac{p^{2}_{j}}{2m}+\sum_{i<j}\frac{1}{2}k(R_{i}-R_{j})^{2}$$

To solve this problem I have used orthogonal jacobi coordinates $$\eta_{j}= \sqrt{\frac{j}{j+1}}\Bigg[\frac{1}{j}\sum_{k=1}^{j}R_{k}-R_{j+1}\Bigg] $$ and $j$ runs from $1$ to $n-1$ and the last linear transformation is $$\eta_{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}R_{j}$$. This transformation completely decouples the above Hamiltonian. However, for the case of non idendtical particles (particles with different masses), this problem becomes much more difficult to find the linear transformation which does decoupling. I have used weigted jacobi coordinates, $$\eta_{k}=\Bigg(\frac{m_{k}}{M_{k}M_{k-1}}\Bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}\Bigg[\sum_{j}m_{j}(R_{k}-R_{j})\Bigg]$$ where.$$M_{k}=\sum_{j=1}^{k}m_{j}$$

Here as usual the last transformation ($n$ th transformation is Centre of Mass coordinate). This mass weigted transfomation completely decouples the kinetic part$$T=\sum_{j}^{n}\frac{p_{j}^{2}}{2m_{j}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2}p_{\eta_{k}}^2$$. However for the case of the potential part,$$V=\sum_{i<j}\frac{1}{2}km_{i}m_{j}(R_{i}-R_{j})^{2}=\frac{1}{M_{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\eta_{k}^{2}$$

Unless I multiply the spring constant with $$m_{i}m_{j}$$ I am not able to decouple the harmonic interaction term. Is there any other better linear transformation which will decouple the harmonic oscillator completely.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that it does not have a closed form solution for arbitrary masses and arbitrary number of particles.

Comment: This hamiltonian can be decoupled and the solution has the form $f(x) \cdot g(y) \cdot h(z) $. In this way the problem is reduced from 3D to 1D.

Comment: We can convert this problem into one dimension yet we cannot solve it in one dimensional as well...

Comment: Unless i multiply the spring constant with $m_{i}m_{j}$. I couldn't reduced it into three dimensional oscillator